# How to run mongodb by making an account

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to Mongodb. So, sorry if my question is preliminary. I need to start MongoDb by  mongod --dbpath mongodb/data/db but I get the error that mongodb command is not found. I saw in many github codes and stackoverflow that others download and install mongodb but when I visit monodb website instead of download I saw the option "No download necessary Deploy a free cluster now" by making an account. I made an account and did not download it. How can I use that account and run mongodb in a way that I do not get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution and I put it heere for usage of others in the same case. I downloaeded mongodb from the main site.
I tried the tutorial for starting mongodb but I got errors that took time for me. I was in ubuntu 16. Finally I changed the ubuntu version and found these three commands in a youtube video which solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
sudo apt-get update
sudo service mongodb start
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here we go.

First things first, if you want to launch MongoDB on your local machine, try to download & install the latest community version from [MongoDB site](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community)

As for the start by `mongod --dbpath mongodb/data/db`. Full launch & install guide you could found [at Mongo Docs site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/).

But let's skip the docs part and take to the real case.

Before executing `mongod` use `cd "path_to_mongod"`

> *For example it will be "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\bin" for Windows*

You don't need to use `--dbpath mongodb/data/db` argument every time. Just [use the config file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file).

Create DBA (root) account and make sure that your MongoDB use `--auth`, before making it available via http(s). **Mongo doesn't have a password by default!**

Comment: Thank you. In implementing the second paragraph, I get error when I use apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.0.4 mongodb-org-server=4.0.4 mongodb-org-shell=4.0.4 mongodb-org-mongos=4.0.4 mongodb-org-tools=4.0.4

Comment: the errors are :Unable to locate package mongodb-org, Unable to locate package mongodb-org-shell, Unable to locate package mongodb-org-mongos
, Unable to locate package mongodb-org-tools
@AlexZeDim

Comment: Is this way works for atlas? I heard mongodb atlas is for free.

Comment: never tried it, but tbh, Mongo Atlas is for free <500MB, so I'm not sure it will suites your needs when you project become something more.
As for my answer it's not relevant for Atlas because it's a cloud version of Mongo, And community is for local/VPS/VDS use

Comment: @parvaneh and if you find my answer useful just mark is as a solution or vote up, please.

Comment: I changed the ubuntu to 18.04 and used the first two command in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WH5GgHaEy7E and I could install the downloaded version.