# npm install mongo/mongodb in VS Code

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code

Im trying to build a REST API. First of all, I have to set up my environment ( MongoDb and Nodejs ) and a text editor . I've choosen VS Code. I opened my Integrated Terminal. I installed mongo using this command ( `npm install mongo` ). And to be sure I installed twice using instructions from the mongdb documentation ..

However , when I'm typing out a command ( `npm mongo --version` ) it says that "mongo " is not an internal command . It means that mongo does not exist. I'm getting confused and I need help!!

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: Im using Windows 8.1

Comment: Difference is that you installed mongodb client library for js, not mongo db itself. Check mongo db official site for more details on how to install database engine itself

Comment: @VijayRajpurohit After fixing the path problem and following the steps below ... Im typing in my cmd prompt on windows ( mongod ) and then it displays that thay are waiting for connections on port 27017 ..However when im typing in my internal terminal in visual studio code this command ( mongod ) it doesnt display anything and it seems via the result on the terminal that mongod is not installed ....Im getting confused !!

Comment: would you add logs in your question, that will help me understand your actual problem?

Comment: @VijayRajpurohit Like i said before,after Installing mongo DB and configuring the path in the local variables ( stpes you gave me earlier ),I typed this command ( mongod ) in my command prompt on windows and it displays this result : "waiting for connections on port 27017".hence , it works    However , when i come back to my integral terminal  in my text editor (Visual studio code)..I type this command ( mongod ).I expected that it displays this result (waiting for connections on port 27017) like the result in my command prompt .Unfortunately,it displays this result ( command not found )

Comment: Try typical connection string for a local MongoDB instance: ```mongodb://localhost:27017```

Comment: @VijayRajpurohit it doesnt Work !

Comment: Had you installed any extension for MongoDB in Visual studio code?

Comment: it works now in my terminal !! it seems very weird o_O

Comment: @ZakariaBelassal lol, however, I updated my answer too, assuming that you have not installed the extension. And if my answer was helpful please accept mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the mongo command from outside, for that you have to add the mongo executable to PATH.

Search for your MongoDb installation bin folder and copy the path (MongoDB executables will be found in "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin").

Right click My Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > System variables > Look for "Path" > Edit > New > Paste in the path to your Mongodb bin folder > Restart your terminal.

Hope this will help you :)

**UPDATED**

I think you have not installed the extension for handling your database.

Refer [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/mongodb) for installing extension Azure Cosmos DB extension and establishing the connection with local Mongo server.

Comment: In most cases `PATH` directory creates w/o user interference during normal installation process and the `latest` version of community mongo is `4.2` so in his case it will `/Server/4.2/bin`

Comment: @ZakariaBelassal if this answer or any other solves your problem don't forget to mark it as `answered` or `helpful`

Comment: Yes, @AlexZeDim whatever version of MongoDB he is using, it will be replaced by  that.

Answer (score 2):

Installation of `MongoDB` have nothing relevant with `npm` commands, especially with `mongo` package.

First of all, you should decide what version of `MongoDB` you'd like to use: `Atlas` or `Community`. If you decide to use `Community` you should download it to your local machine from [this part of official MongoDB site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/), after installation, [check out this manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/), and then try to use Mongo Shell. And create a DBA (root) account for your database, you can find more info about it in official doc part, or here: [in my answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53826455/how-to-run-mongodb-by-making-an-account/53828517#53828517).

Right after correct installation, you should choose to decide what driver for `Node.js` you will use. Most of users decide between *[native Mongo Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)* and *[mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)* And this is where `npm` or `yarn` comes out of darkness. You could install native mongoDB driver via: `npm install mongodb --save` or mongoose via: `npm install mongoose`. Try to choose wisely.

Comment: I have seen your post for installation. nice answer bro :)  you deserve a cookie and upvote both. +1 from my side.